# Factory method 'amazonS3Client' : Access key cannot be null

Tags: spring-boot

Trying to connect with aws-s3 using spring boot application. when i am using

> import org.springframework.cloud.aws.context.support.io.ResourceLoaderBeanPostProcessor

getting aws key can not be null.

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableContextResourceLoader
 @EnableContextCredentials
 public class S3Configuration {

        @Value("${cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey}")
        private String ACCESS_KEY;
        @Value("${cloud.aws.credentials.secretKey}")
        private String SECRET_KEY;

        @Value("${cloud.aws.region}")
        private String region;

@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}

@Bean
public AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client() {
    return new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY));
}

@Bean
public ResourceLoaderBeanPostProcessor resourceLoaderBeanPostProcessor() {
    return new ResourceLoaderBeanPostProcessor(amazonS3Client());
}
}
```

If I dont use "ResourceLoaderBeanPostProcessor" class then AmazonS3Client object is creating successfully by reading properties form application.properties.

can some one help me what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that the `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` class that the `ResourceLoaderBeanPostProcessor` implements, is executed before values from `application.properties` are loaded/injected by the spring application. Therefore your values (when creating the bean) is `null`. (And that's why it works when you're not using that paticular class).

I would suggest using the default credentials chain, and have your credentials lying in a `~/.aws/` folder (on your local machine, and on your servers). see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html for more detail.

Comment: This answer worked in 2023. Trying to load some packages and as you say `gradle.properties` loads after some dependencies.